# how to load method of library to each thread QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a method like that

```
QString process::excute(QString params_json_string) {

QVariantMap data = QtJson::parse(params_json_string).toMap();
QVariantMap params = data["data"].toMap();
QString client_action = data["action"].toString();

QList<mylib> listlib = listaction(client_action); // fuction listaction return list my library

for (int j = 0; j < listlib.size(); ++j) {

    string show = listlib[j].shobject->excute2("json_string");
    qDebug() << "--" << QString::fromUtf8(show.c_str());
}

return "OK";}
```

Now I would like load method `execute2` from my library to each thread, and each method in thread will process separate 'json_string' input. Anyone give me an suggest method, links reference or simple qt code . thanks all